# AutoFixture+Moq - Freezing a mocked class prevent from setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture

I'd like to understand why my test fails when I'm freezing a mocked class instead of an mocked interface

```
[Fact]
public void MethodeName()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

    var webRequestMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<MyWebRequest>>(); // freezing a class + setuping a return value
    webRequestMock.Setup(a => a.GetData())
    .Returns("Foo");

    var myService = fixture.Create<MyService>();

    var actual = myService.GetData();

    webRequestMock.Verify(a => a.GetData(), Times.Once()); // Failed it's never called once
    Assert.Equal("Foo", actual); // Failed, if we comment previous line, 'actual' value is always empty
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyWebRequest _request;

    public MyService(MyWebRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var data = _request.GetData();
        return data;
    }
}

public class MyWebRequest 
{
    public virtual string GetData() // you can see here, the method is well virtual, and should be overridable by moq.
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**1/** If I try with a mocked interface, it works.

```
[Fact]
public void MethodeName()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    const string expected = "Foo";

    var webRequestMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IMyWebRequest>>();
    webRequestMock.Setup(a => a.GetData())
    .Returns("Foo");

    var myService = fixture.Create<MyService>();

    var actual = myService.GetData();

    webRequestMock.Verify(a => a.GetData(), Times.Once()); // Success
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual); // Success
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IMyWebRequest _request;

    public MyService(IMyWebRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var data = _request.GetData();
        return data;
    }
}

public interface IMyWebRequest
{
    string GetData();
}

public class MyWebRequest : IMyWebRequest
{
    public virtual string GetData()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**2/** If I use 'inject' instead of freeze, it works:

```
[Fact]
public void MethodeName()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    const string expected = "Foo";

    var webRequestMock = new Mock<MyWebRequest>(); 
    webRequestMock.Setup(a => a.GetData()).Returns("Foo");
    fixture.Inject(webRequestMock.Object);

    var myService = fixture.Create<MyService>();

    var actual = myService.GetData();

    webRequestMock.Verify(a => a.GetData(), Times.Once()); // Success
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual); // Success
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly MyWebRequest _request;

    public MyService(MyWebRequest request)
    {
        _request = request;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var data = _request.GetData();
        return data;
    }
}

public class MyWebRequest 
{
    public virtual string GetData()
    {
        // make WebRequest
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My autofixture version: 3.6.5.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MyWebRequest` is a concrete (non-abstract) class, and *AutoFixture.AutoMoq* doesn't create those using *Moq*. This is **by design**, since the *AutoFixture* kernel already deals with creation of 'normal' classes.

[You can change this behaviour](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/25/ChangingthebehaviorofAutoFixtureauto-mockingwithMoq) if you'd like. Often, though, I'd consider having to do this a design smell. It's difficult to tell in this case, though, because you've done a good job of reducing the problem to a minimal repro. The problem with this, though, is that as presented here, `MyService` doesn't add any value. I'm sure that's not what your real code looks like, but since I can't guess what your real code looks like, I can't tell if a better design would be possible.